# HARDCODED_CREDENTIALS warning with OS environment variables file when using Coverity Scan

Tags: python, environment-variables, credentials, coverity, hardcoded

I used `Coverity Scan` to scan my Python project and got the

> HARDCODED_CREDENTIALS warning

which indicated that it was unsafe for me to read the password from the Linux environment variable file. Specifically, I read the password as follows:

```
import os
MY_PASSWORD=os.getenv("MYPASSWD","owner")
```

And I use it to connect to `MySQL` as follows:

```
mysql_conn=pymysql.connect(password=MY_PASSWORD,...)
```

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: Well, 'owner' is a hard coded default...

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson so how can i fix this? just remove "owner" ?

Comment: Yes, remove the `"owner"` string. You should not hardcode a default value for something sensitive like a password. You should instead fail if the env var isn't set.